# How to debug Ionic Angular navigateByUrl() when not working on first time rendering of page

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic angular app decoding. In the first time rendering of a page in a browser. the `navigateByUrl()` is not working. after changing URL in the browser to forward a page and getting back to the previous page. Then router `navigateByUrl()` is working. How to make it work at the first place. the following is the required code.

```
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/contents');
```

Comment: Thanks @sarvesh-mahajan for improving this question

Comment: Can you share some more code, why are you expecting navigatebyurl method to be called on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works you might have making some mistakes

Comment: Yeah it's working. Later I checked and it worked and this problem solved.